# select statement - update the value of one field with a fixed value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a select statement that returns a few fields from a table.

I want to update only the results of that select, giving a fixed value in one field.

I though of that, but it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE

 (SELECT * from table.... where...)

SET field1=1
```

Comment: You can supply a where clause to an update statement.

Comment: Are the two (or more) tables related? Can you join them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are using t-sql

```
UPDATE 
SET field = fixed value
from tablename
where filed....
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't need a `SELECT`, just use a `WHERE` clause directly with the `UPDATE` to do this only for the rows that statify the condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE t
SET field1 = 1
FROM table AS t
WHERE ...
```